# Why is this postgres sql command not giving the creation result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

```
CREATE TABLE googlepolitics (
"County" text, 
"State" text, 
"FIPS code" int, 
"Week of: 01 / 03 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 01 / 10 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 01 / 17 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 01 / 24 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 01 / 31 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 02 / 07 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 02 / 14 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 02 / 21 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 02 / 28 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 03 / 07 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 03 / 14 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 03 / 21 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 03 / 28 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 04 / 04 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 04 / 11 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 04 / 18 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 04 / 25 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 05 / 02 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 05 / 09 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 05 / 16 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 05 / 23 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 05 / 30 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 06 / 06 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 06 / 13 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 06 / 20 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 06 / 27 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 07 / 04 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 07 / 11 / 2020" text, 
"Week of: 07 / 18 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 07 / 25 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 08 / 01 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 08 / 08 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 08 / 15 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 08 / 22 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 08 / 29 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 09 / 05 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 9 / 12 / 2020" text, 
"Week of: 9 / 19 / 2020" text, 
"Week of: 9 / 26 / 2021" text, 
"Week of :10 / 03 / 2021" text, 
"Week of: 10 / 10" text, 
"Week of: 10 / 17" text, 
"Week of: 10 / 24" text, 
"Week of: 10 / 31" text, 
"Week of: 11 / 07" text, 
"Week of: 11 / 14" text, 
"Week of: 11 / 21" text, 
"Week of: 11 / 28" text, 
"Week of: 12 / 05" text, 
"Week of: 12 / 12" text, 
"Week of: 12 / 19" text, 
"Week of: 12 / 26" text
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju0CW.png)

Comment: where did you run this query ? post the error you got while you running the query?

Comment: generally if it not fail then it works. if it works then a  table is created. create table don't have any message like table is created.

Comment: Syntactically there is nothing wrong with your statement, however a table with no keys , where all columns can be null and a lot of repeting columns is usually not a sign of a good data model.

Comment: If you did this in transaction and did not commit it then the table would not persist past the session.